# Probability proof for independence of hash function

Tags: probability

I'm not really sure how to approach this problem, any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Consider the hash function $ h(u) = au + b $ mod 13.

We showed that for every $ u\neq u'$ and $v, v'$ where $u, u', v, v' \in$ {0, 1, 2,...,12} then

$Pr[h(u) = v \cap h(u') = v'] = \frac{1}{13^2}$

as long as $a$ and $b$ are randomly chosen from {0, 1,...,12} and are independent of each other and of $u, u', v, v'$.

Now let's suppose that only b is chosen independently of $u, u', v, v'$. However, $u, u', v, v'$ are allowed to depend on a. Is the following true, or false?

$Pr[h(u)=v \cap h(u') = v'] = \frac{1}{(13^2)} $for every $u \neq u$ and $v, v'$where $u,u',v,v' \in {0, 1,...,12}$

Answer (score 0):

No; the most we can guarantee is that the probability is between $0$ and $\frac1{13}$.

We can choose $u, u', v, v'$ so that $$v - au \equiv v' - au' \pmod {13}.\tag{1}$$ For example, we can do this by choosing $u, u', v'$ arbitrarily, and letting $v = au - au' + v' \bmod {13}$.

If that's the case, then with probability $\frac1{13}$, $b$ will happen to be equal to $v - au \bmod {13}$, so that $h(u) = au + b \bmod {13}$ will equal $v$. But if that's the case, then $b$ is *also* automatically equal to $v' - au' \bmod {13}$, and so $h(u') = au' + b \bmod {13}$ will equal $v'$.

In other words, the events $h(u)=v$ and $h(u')=v'$ are no longer independent, but happen simultaneously or not at all.

On the other hand, by making a different choice of $v$ at the end, we can guarantee that $(1)$ is false. This will have the opposite effect: now, whenever $h(u) = v$, we know that $h(u') \ne v'$, and the two events never occur together.